# Cannot get iteration count of for loop cycle inside of the service result -> then

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, service, global-variables

i have following method:

```
var i;
$scope.playAllSelectedSounds = function() {
            try {

                for( i; i < $scope.selectedSounds.length; i++) {
                    var fileName = $scope.selectedSounds[i].file;
                    var volume = $scope.selectedSounds[i].defaultVolume;
                    var filePath  = "sounds/" +fileName+".mp3";
                    console.log(fileName);
                    MediaSrv.loadMedia(filePath).then(function(media){
                        console.log(media);
                        // !!!!!!!!!!!  HERE I CANNOT GET value of the i VARIABLE
                        $scope.selectedSounds[i].state = 1;
                        // !!!!!!!!!!!  HERE I CANNOT GET value of the i VARIABLE
                        $scope.selectedSounds[i].mediaInstance = media;
                        media.play();
                        media.setVolume(volume);
                    });

                }
            } catch(e) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                console.log(e);
                $scope.showAlert("Error", "Error during the playing item");
            }
        };
```

Problem is that inside of the service:

```
                MediaSrv.loadMedia(filePath).then(function(media){
```

I cannot get number o for cycle loop which i need to set in:

```
                $scope.selectedSounds[i].state = 1;
```

Variable **i** is global i still cannot reach them. How can i solve it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not because `i` is not accessible, it is because `i` has run out of its limit because `loadMedia` is async and the value of `i` within the callback would become `$scope.selectedSounds.length`, since the for loop would have run out before the callback is invoked.

You could resolve this by using a closure variable representing the current item: You could just make use angular.forEach itself, and you don't event need to worry about accessing the right index. Instead just modify the object itself which is available as 1st argument of `forEach` evaluator function.

```
      angular.forEach($scope.selectedSounds, function loadMedia(selectedSound, idx){
           var fileName = selectedSound.file;
            var volume = selectedSound.defaultVolume;
            var filePath  = "sounds/" +fileName+".mp3";

            MediaSrv.loadMedia(filePath).then(function(media){
                selectedSound.state = 1;
                selectedSound.mediaInstance = media;
                media.play();
                media.setVolume(volume);
            });

     });
```

*Also you forgot to initialize `i` in your case, which will cause your loop to not run at all.*

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you create a local variable var that=i; just before your call to the promise, and then try to get "that" inside the promise return?

Otherwise try this :

```
 for (var i in superarray){
    (function(j) {
        MyService.get(superarray[j].externalID).then(function(r) {
            console.debug(j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```